# Logstash get only message content

Tags: logstash

I would like to read a file line-by-line and put only the rows into a queue.
The process works but in the queue there are a lot of other information such as version and so one.

Do you have any idea?

Here is my config file:

```
input {
   file {
     codec => plain
     path => "/apps/*.txt"
  }
}
filter{

}
output {
    stomp {
        host => "localhost"
        port => "61613"
        destination => "stomp-test"
        debug => "true"
        headers => {
                "amq-msg-type" => "text"
                "my_custom_header" => "kutya"
        }
    }
}
```

The example.txt contains:
This is my test row!

The MQ body contains:
{"message":"This is my test row!","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2017-01-21T13:42:21.084Z","path":"/apps/1.txt","host":"ol7"}

My expected result should be:
This is my test row!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stomp` output, as it currently stands, will only write JSON to the destination queue as can be seen [in the source code](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-stomp/blob/master/lib/logstash/outputs/stomp.rb#L86) of that plugin:

```
t.send(event.sprintf(@destination), event.to_json, headers)
                                          ^
                                          |
                                     writes JSON
```

The best you can do is to remove all other fields using a [`mutate/remove_field` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html), like this:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["@timestamp", "@version", "path", "host"]
  }
}
```

Then you'll get only this in your destination queue:

```
{"message":"This is my test row!"}
```

Answer (score 3):

I came across this question looking for a similar solution.

Your question can be solved using codec.

Add this line to your output:

```
      codec => line { format => "%{message}"}
```

It will look like this:

```
output {
    stomp {
        host => "localhost"
        port => "61613"
        destination => "stomp-test"
        debug => "true"
        codec => line { format => "%{message}"}
        headers => {
                "amq-msg-type" => "text"
                "my_custom_header" => "kutya"
        }
    }
}
```